# Serialization/deserialization with GZIP Sterams isn't consitent

Tags: java, serialization, gzip, throwable

I have the following peace of code that tries to serialize/deserialize a `Throwable`

```
public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    IllegalStateException exception = new IllegalStateException("Oooops!");

    ByteBuffer seralized = serialize(exception);
    String asString = new String(seralized.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    Throwable deserialized = deserialize(seralized);

    // false
    System.out.println(exception.equals(deserialized));
    // true
    System.out.println(exception.toString().equals(deserialized.toString()));

    seralized = serialize(deserialized);
    String toCompare = new String(seralized.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    // true
    System.out.println(asString.equals(toCompare));
}

private Throwable deserialize(ByteBuffer seralized) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return (Throwable) new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(seralized.array()))).readObject();
}

private ByteBuffer serialize(Throwable exception) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream causeBytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream causeOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
                                         new GZIPOutputStream(causeBytesOut));
    causeOut.writeObject(exception);
    causeOut.close();
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(causeBytesOut.toByteArray());
}
```

Explaining the code: I am testing that my serialization/deserialization is compatible.

The first print out (false) tells me that whatever I got after deserialization is different then what I serialized.

The second print (true) tells that the objects are "somewhat" similar.

I tried to dig into each object to see what is the difference, so I serialized it again and looked at the content of the byte buffer. Which looks to be the same according to the last print (true).

Why are the initial object and the one that went though serialization/deserialization different although seem to be the same?

Comment: `toString` will simple print `java.lang.llegalStateException`, its coming from `Throwable#String()`, so you cannot say 'its "somewhat" similar'. Also both `asString` and `toCompare` are exactly same (by the way in which you create those strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly find the below explanation for the result that you observe.

1. calling `toString` on an object of type `IllegalStateException` will simply return the fully qualified class name. This is coming from `Throwable#toString()`. Hence this is same for both objects, the result of `equals` will be true

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException
   ```
2. `IllegalStateException` or its parents do not override `equals` method. Hence will equate to only itself. Since your deserialization will create a new object, your objects don't equal in reference, hence `equals` will return false (as per `Object#equals`).
3. You are creating both `asString` and `toCompare` exact same way, using the below expression, also since these two different string objects with same content will equate, your 3rd expression is true.

   ```
   new String(seralized.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   ```

If you need to have the deserialized object return true on calling `equals()` with the original object, you can subclass `IllegalStateException` and override `equals` method  (also `toString` in this case.).

Answer (score 1):

`IllegalStateException` does not override `Object.equals()`, so it uses object identity via the `==` operator. It will therefore always return false for distinct instances.

Your test is invalid.